# 'Un' vs 'le' for days

Tags: articles-definis

> Nous sommes **le** lundi
>
> Nous sommes **un** lundi

> Je suis né **un** vingt-cinq décembre.
>
> Je suis né **le** vingt-cinq décembre.

What's the difference in meaning in both pairs?

Comment: When would you ever say: "Today is a Monday"? Unless you are a patient coming out of a coma and the nurse or someone tells you that. Or something like that. Same for the birth date. You wouldn't say I was  born on "a December 25th", That would be highly unlikely.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'on ne le dise pas en anglais ne présuppose rien sur le français pour qui d'ailleurs *nous sommes un lundi* et *je suis né un 25 décembre* sont parfaitement idiomatiques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nous sommes le lundi", as is, is not used; there must be precisions added as to what "lundi" you are talking about; what you can use is "Nous sommes  lundi." or "Nous sommes un lundi.", but this last one is not much in favour.

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nous+sommes+lundi%2C+nous+sommes+un+lundi&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20lundi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20un%20lundi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20lundi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnous%20sommes%20un%20lundi%3B%2Cc0)

"Je suis né un" is essentially used for days in a nominal form.

- je suis né un vendredi
- je suis née un lundi de Paques
- je suis né un jour férié
- je suis né un jour d'hiver

The forms of the type "un < day of the week > " is not found  often (exception : vendredi 13).

([ref. 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_hiver_des_enfants_vol%C3%A9s/hofFCQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+suis+n%C3%A9+un%22&pg=PT155&printsec=frontcover)) Je suis né un 1er janvier et ça m'a toujours amusé. Quelle idée de naître le jour de l'an ? Mais la probabilité de naître un 1er janvier n'est-elle pas la même que celle de voir le jour un 18 mai, un 27 juin, ou à une tout autre date ?

([ref. 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Eug%C3%A8ne_Labiche_Oeuvres_Compl%C3%A8tes/etW4DAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+suis+n%C3%A9+un%22&pg=PT6550&printsec=frontcover)) Je suis né un vendredi 13!... Dès que je touche à quelque chose... crac!... ça casse... Si je veux jouer aux dominos, je perds...

However, it is also used for the date as a number of the month followed by the name of the month.

([ref. 1, 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_tout_en_un_3e_Nouveau_brevet/iGmCDAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+suis+n%C3%A9+un%22&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover)) Cette ampleur de front est en rapport (selon le dire des astrologues) avec le signe du Bélier ; et en effet je suis né un 20 avril, donc aux confins de ces deux signes : le Bélier et le Taureau.

([ref. 2, 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_hiver_des_enfants_vol%C3%A9s/hofFCQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22je+suis+n%C3%A9+un%22&pg=PT155&printsec=frontcover)) Mais la probabilité de naître un 1er janvier n'est-elle pas la même que celle de voir le jour un 18 mai, un 27 juin, ou à une tout autre date ?

"Je suis né le" is used both for the date as a number followed by the month and possibly the year, ans also for the date as the name of the week followed by the number of the month and possibly the year.

- je suis né le 20 aout 1989.
- je suis née le vendredi 18 avril 2O01

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+suis+n%C3%A9+un%2Cje+suis+n%C3%A9+le&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20n%C3%A9%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20n%C3%A9%20le%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20n%C3%A9%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20n%C3%A9%20le%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: *Nous somme le lundi* is very common provided which Monday it is is stated: *Nous sommes le lundi 6 décembre* or *Nous sommes le lundi qui précède notre départ pour 12 semaines à Madagascar avec un vol prévu le samedi*.